# R use grep to clean column in list of lists

Tags: r, lapply

I have a large data set stored as a list of lists that may be simplified thus:

```
list1 <- list(1,"bob", "age=14;years")
list2 <- list(2,"bill", "age=24;years")
list3 <- list(3,"bert", "age=36;years")

data.list <- list(list1, list2, list3)
```

I wish to clean the third column such that I have only the numeric value of age. 
This can be done with the following function that returns a new list:

```
clean <- function(x){
  x <- as.numeric(gsub('.*age=(.*?);.*','\\1', x[3]))
}

data.age <- lapply(data.list, clean)
```

But how may I either

a) directly clean the column to return the value

or

b) replace the origional column `[3]` with the `data.age` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the list back in your function, so modify your function as:

```
clean <- function(x){
  x[[3]] <- as.numeric(gsub('.*age=(.*?);.*','\\1', x[[3]]))
  x
}

data.age <- lapply(data.list, clean)
```

should do the trick.